# Print i prints repeated number twice, is there any method for printing it only once

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code

```
tup = (1,2,3,4,5,6,6)
for i in tup:
    if (tup.count(i)<1):
        print(i)
```

And it's output is

```
6
6
```

But i want it's output should only prints once. What logic do I need to add and why it's printing twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(tup).items() if count > 1])
```

in this case it is printing twice, because it is iterating every element in your TUP and there are two 6 es, and 6 is more than 1

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: did not understand you, please clearify

Comment: I run the above code and it gave the following error

Comment: lol, it is wokring on my machine